# Python FileNotFoundError for user input

Tags: python, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am making a program that encrypts the contents of a file into cipher text. My problem is that when my program asks the user to input the name of the file they want to load and the user doesn't give a valid response, then the "FileNotFoundError:" shows up. I want my program to have a function where if the user doesnt give a valid response, the program will keep telling the user to retry.

```
def EncryptCode():
    encryptFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n") 
    with open (encryptFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
        encryptFile = encrypt_file.read()
```

I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

i have tried doing something like this:

```
def EncryptCode():
    ...
    try:
        ...
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return EncryptCode
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
def EncryptCode():
    file_not_found = True
    while(file_not_found):
        try:
            encryptFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n")
            file_not_found = False
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('that didnt work! try again')
    with open (encryptFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
        encryptFile = encrypt_file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it. Check http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php  It should be something like this:

```
def EncryptCode():
    try:
        encryptFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n")
        with open(encryptFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
            encryptFile = encrypt_file.read()
            return encryptFile
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found. Input correct filename')
        return EncryptCode()
```

Or you can use `while` loop to ask user input correct filename like:

```
while True:
    try:
        encryptFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n")
        with open (encryptFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
            encryptFile = encrypt_file.read()
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found. Input correct filename')
```